# Disable a button for 30 seconds when pressed, enable again, then disabled when pressed again

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uibutton

I am trying to get this done. I want a button, that gets disabled once it is pressed for a certain amount of time. And once that time is over, the button is enabled again until it is pressed again, which then disables it for set time. I do not want the button to be enabled again easily by restarting the app. It has to stay disabled until the time is over and not until the next launch of the app .. so far my code is only working to disable the button once. It is not working, to enable it again after the time has passed. also the button is enabled again right after I relaunch the app. That is not supposed to happen.

Anyone have an idea, how I can get it working the way I want it to?

This is the code I have:

```
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { _ in
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
})
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer2), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

with the @objc being:

```
@objc func fireTimer() {
    print("Timer fired!")
}

@objc func fireTimer2() {
    print("Start timer.")
}
```

With this I wanted to try, if I can set a start time and a repeating time in the hopes to get things going with the button. I did not.
Can anyone help me?

Appreciate it a lot! All the best

UPDATE, June 29:

This here is the code, I use for my button and to make the disable/enable function, that I want, work.

```
 @objc private let actionButton: UIButton = {
   let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Button Title", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 16)
    button.setTitleColor(.secondaryLabel, for: .normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchDown)

return button
}()

@objc func didTapButton() {
self.actionButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 20, repeats: true) { _ in
    self.actionButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}}
```

So how do I store the data from the timer in the `core data`(???) or `UserDefaults`(???) or where ever, so the timer doesnt reset when relaunching the app?

Comment: Have you tried adding a time to `UserDefaults` your timer/init methods could check the "nextAvailableTime" variable

Comment: Use the grand dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

The `Timer` class has an initializer [`init(fire:interval:repeats:block)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091887-init) that allows you to set a `Date` when it will fire. This will be useful for your problem. You have to be a little careful to make sure that you don't forget to schedule the timer, otherwise it will never fire.

You can use this to write a method like this:

```swift
func disable(button buttonToDisable: UIButton, until date: Date) {
    buttonToDisable.isEnabled = false
    let timer  = Timer.init(fire: date, interval: 0, repeats: false) { _ in
        buttonToDisable.isEnabled = true
    }
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
}
```

This method disables a specified button until a given date. Notice that `false` is passed for the `repeats` parameter. We only want this to run once.

With this method in hand you can now do the following when your button is pressed:

```swift
let disabledTimeInterval = TimeInterval(30.0)
    
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let disabledUntil = Date().advanced(by: disabledTimeInterval)
    disable(button: self.button, until: disabledUntil)
}
```

This takes care of enabling and disabling the button while the app is running. But you also mentioned that you don't want users to be able to stop and start your app to get around the time out. You can handle this by saving the date the button should be disabled until in `UserDefaults`. The following code show how you can save and load a `Date` to `UserDefaults`.

```swift
    let buttonDisabledUntilDateKey = "buttonDisabledUntil"

    func save(disabledUntilDate date: Date) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(date, forKey: buttonDisabledUntilDateKey)
    }
    
    func loadDisabledUntilDate() -> Date? {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: buttonDisabledUntilDateKey) as? Date
    }
```

You can now modify the `buttonPressed` method to save this data:

```swift
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let disabledUntil = Date().advanced(by: disabledTimeInterval)
    save(disabledUntilDate: disabledUntil)
    disable(button: self.button, until: disabledUntil)
}
```

Finally, when your view is about to appear, you should check whether the current time is before the time when the button should be reenabled and, if necessary, disable it.

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let now = Date()
    if let buttonDisabledUntilDate = loadDisabledUntilDate(),
       now < buttonDisabledUntilDate {
        disable(button: self.button, until: buttonDisabledUntilDate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the UserDefaults stuff did not work for me. I managed to create a button that once it is pressed, is disabled for a certain amount of time and is then enabled again until it is pressed once again. But whenever I relaunch the app, the timer is reset. Is there another way for me to save that timer data in the UserDefaults so it does not reset when relaunching?

Comment: The timer cannot survive the relaunch. You will have to recreate it and reset it with the saved date. Perhaps post the exact code you are using and someone will be able to help you out. The key part is the `viewWillAppear` stuff are you sure yo implemented it correctly?

Comment: The code you shared does not appear to use any of the code in my answer. For example you don’t use `init(fire:interval:repeats:block)`, you don’t save anything to `UserDefaults` nor do you reload data from when you app restarts. Try using the code in the answer.